# hook_form_alter makes js on every other form not work

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I use `hook_form_alter()` to alter a field.

```php
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'my_form') {
    $form['my_field']['#value'] = 'New value';
  }
}
```

It changes the field value to new value, but the problem is that, as soon as I enable this module, the JavaScript on forms stops working. For example drop-downs, autocomplete, AJAX no longer works.

I cant understand what cause this.

Comment: Try changing the theme temporarily (to any of the themes included with core that you are not already using) and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: You are misdiagnosing your problem, as this code would not cause the issue you are facing.

Comment: Check the browser's console for JS errors.

Comment: @Jaypan is correct: That code could not cause issues with JavaScript code. You don't get the form ID from `$form['#id']`, but that is another matter.

Comment: Also, before setting `$form['my_field']['#value']`, you should check `$form['my_field']` has been set.